# Angular 2 dynamic component generation, ts compilation error

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, compilation, angular2-components

I can create dynamic component by using this method:

```
public addItem<T extends WidgetComponent>(ngItem: {new(): T}): T {
    let factory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ngItem);
    const ref = this._viewCntRef.createComponent(factory);
    const newItem: T = ref.instance as T;
    ...
    return newItem;
  }
```

And call it like this:

```
const ref: MyWidgetComponent = this.dashboard.addItem<MyWidgetComponent>(MyWidgetComponent);
```

But typescript put me this compilation error: 
`app.component.ts:45:35 
Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`

I try to replace `{new(): T}` by `Type<T>` but I have the same error: `app.component.ts:45:35 
Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`

What is the correct definition here ? Because the code work great...

EDIT: here is the full code if you want to see it in place https://github.com/jaumard/ng2-dashboard/blob/master/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts#L99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix compilation error by changing the signature to :

```
public addItem(ngItem: Type<WidgetComponent>): WidgetComponent
```

And the call like this :

```
const ref: MyWidgetComponent = this.dashboard.addItem(MyWidgetComponent) as MyWidgetComponent;
```